# How to accept input of Array of Object in swagger UI Api

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to create an API to accept an input with Json Array. This array can accept both string and Int. based on the Input, I will be performing the required logic. Below is my DTO class

```
@Data
public class NoticeDto {

@Data
public static class CreateNotice {

    @JsonProperty(value = "sender", required = true)
    private int sender;

    @JsonProperty(value = "dialog", required = true)
    private String dialog;

   @JsonProperty(value = "site_name", required = true)
    private String site_name;

    @JsonProperty( value = "receivers", required = true )
    private List<Object> receivers;

  }
}
```

[image]

How will the user understand to input data in this format?

```
{
  "dialog": "Test Msg to Test MAn 17",
  "receivers": [
    15 , 25 , 35
  ],
  "sender": 89706,
  "site_name": "S7"
}
```

Or

```
{
  "dialog": "Test Msg to Test MAn 15",
  "receivers": [
    "R15" , "R25" , "R35"
  ],
  "sender": 89706,
  "site_name": "S5"
}
```

Please let me know how can I change the DTO to accept array input.

Comment: What is `receivers` supposed to be? It should either be a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>`. Then it should be clear to the caller what is allowed and what is not. You will need quotes for the Strings, while quotes are not allowed for the Integers.

`List<Object>` could be anything. Even complex compound objects.

Comment: @JochenReinhardt Yes, `receivers` is supposed to be only `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`

Comment: @JochenReinhardt How should I change DTO to display to accept List<String> or List<Integer> only

Comment: It can't be both at the same time / inside the same DTO. It should either be a List<String> or a List<Integer>. Java is a statically typed language. You have to make a decision in your DTO.

You may have more success defining your API using a swagger file instead of generating one based on Java classes. I found support for mixed-type arrays using 'oneOf' here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/